# Trouble authenticating users in another domain in an Active Directory group

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I have 2 domains: A, B

I have 1 group and it is located in domain A. I can add users fine from either domain to the group.

My problem is authenticating the users in my asp.net app. I can authenticate the users fine if they are from Domain A but not if they're from Domain B. I am using ASP.net 2.0 and authorization manager (AzMan). The provider I am using is System.Web.Security.AuthorizationStoreRoleProvider.

When I look at what is stored in the group for the user from domain B it looks like the following: CN=SID, CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipal, DC=A.

So my question is how do I authenticate cross domain?

Comment: what type of authentication scheme and provider are you making use of?

Comment: Using asp.net RoleManager with windows authentication

Comment: Can you give more precisions, what are the relations between the two domains ? Are then in the same forest. Is there an approbation relation ?